# Problem with mapping external domain to Google Cloud Hosting

Tags: hosting, cloud-hosting

I'm trying to map domain to Google CLoud hosting instance with external fixed ip 34.90.216.44.

In DNS settings of my hostingprovider I've added the records Google advice. See screenshot.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GjIe.png)

But when I go to https://weekendbaard.nl the url is not found on the server.

I'm missing one important step but after hours searching I can't find the solution. Is there somebody who can point me in the right direction?

Regards,
Kees

Comment: I suspect there are a few missed instructions - could you post the ones you followed?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use "www.cloudflare.com" Clouflare records, and they'll give you 1 year free SSL certificate optimisation and much more nice stuff for your website 1 advantage, then try to make sure that you provide all DNS records from Google cloud to your DNS hostingprovider because i think GOOGLE CLOUD gives 4 records not just one and also you should make CNAME and A records :
CNAME as : www.yourdomainename.com
A as : your domain name.X.X.X.X
NS as : yourdomainename.the records Google advice1
NS as : yourdomainename.the records Google advice2
NS as : yourdomainename.the records Google advice3
NS as : yourdomainename.the records Google advice4
"P.S : X.X.X.X = your ip address".
then it'll work fine, Good luck.
```